# How to make dynamic menu with ng-repeat 2 level or or level

Tags: angularjs

I have two objects.

```
1. $scope.modules=[ { "ModuleId": 1, "ModuleName": "Membership" },
                     { "ModuleId": 2, "ModuleName": "Loan" },
                     { "ModuleId": 3, "ModuleName": "News" },
                     { "ModuleId": 4, "ModuleName": "Contact Us" }, 
                     { "ModuleId": 5, "ModuleName": "About Us" }, 
                     { "ModuleId": 6, "ModuleName": "FeedBack" },
                     { "ModuleId": 7, "ModuleName": "Fee" }, 
                     { "ModuleId": 8, "ModuleName": "Home" } ]

 2. $scope.subModules=[ { "ModuleId": 1, "SubModuleId": 1, "SubModuleName": "Get Membership" }, 
                        { "ModuleId": 7, "SubModuleId": 2, "SubModuleName": "Fee Structure" }, 
                        { "ModuleId": 7, "SubModuleId": 3, "SubModuleName": "Fee Submission" }, 
                        { "ModuleId": 1, "SubModuleId": 4, "SubModuleName": "Our Members" }, 
                        { "ModuleId": 7, "SubModuleId": 5, "SubModuleName": "Fee Status" }, 
                        { "ModuleId": 2, "SubModuleId": 6, "SubModuleName": "Loan Structure" }, 
                        { "ModuleId": 2, "SubModuleId": 7, "SubModuleName": "form" }, 
                        { "ModuleId": 1, "SubModuleId": 8, "SubModuleName": "Inquiry" } ]
```

I want to create ,for now, two level dynamic menu having dropdown if menu has submenu.
I want an output like shown in this img...

Tell me how to put ng-repeat in HTML. How to make required json object from above two objects.

[image]

I know how to put html n other stuffs. just help me with ng-repeat and UL and LI. else I'd manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is if you could combine the `modules` array with the `subModules` array, something like this (only including module 1 for clarity):

```
$scope.modules = [
    {ModuleId: 1, ModuleName: 'Membership', SubModules:
        [
             { "ModuleId": 1, "SubModuleId": 1, "SubModuleName": "Get Membership" }
             { "ModuleId": 1, "SubModuleId": 4, "SubModuleName": "Our Members" },
             { "ModuleId": 1, "SubModuleId": 8, "SubModuleName": "Inquiry" } 
        ]
     }
];
```

If your model looks like this, you could easily have nested ng-repeats:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="module in modules">
        {{module.ModuleName}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="subModule in module.SubModules">
                {{subModule.SubModuleName}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

if you for some reason can't get your modules/submodules like that (for intstance loading them from a server you can't control), you can simply create the model by adding this in your controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.modules, function(module){
    module.SubModules = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.subModules, function(subModule){
        if(subModule.ModuleId === module.ModuleId){
            module.SubModules.push(subModule);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This the point where i'm stuck since long time. I dont know how to make one json as you have shown in first snippet. If you could help me from my code.

Comment: In your code, it looks like your modules/submodules arrays are hard-coded. If that's the case, you can simply follow the pattern in my first snippet, placing the submodules in an array inside their module. If you can't control how the JSON looks, you can utilize the code in my third snippet, that will inject the submodules into a "SubModules" field on each module object

Comment: No its not hard coded. Let me try your snippet n let me check.